# You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders in NUXT app and HEROKU platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a NUXT application, hosted on Heroku.
I try to deploy and suddenly I see this issue in the logs which informs me that the build failed.
[image]

I have tried to run the build script locally `npm run build` and it works perfectly.
[image]

Why is my code failing in the cloud but run perfectly locally?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have problems with the npm script that means that the code is fine. Taking a look back I can see that the only thing which is different is the env in which the code runs.
Most of the time the node version which you use locally is different compared with the cloud one and this might bring errors.
Find out your local node version by running `node -v` in the command line.
[image]

After that find out the node version in your cloud provider. In my case is Heroku and the node version is
[image]

There is clearly a difference between them.
To have the same node version running in the cloud as well, add the property engines in the package.json file and describe the node version.

[image]

This will force Heroku, to run my local version of node.js
By doing so the problem disappeared and the build was successful.

[image]